# Data in frequency modulated audio

Tags: encryption

I'd like to have a peek at the firmware of a piece of Hardware. Its firmware is available as a .wav file to be uploaded via audio jack.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6S_PcWWM1YlQnNwT2FSMnFzVE0

And it sure looks like straight forward frequency modulation. I think I can even make out a pattern: useful signal (8 waves, then 4 recurring waves as separator) and once in a while (didnt count the "bytes" inbetween) 0.5ms of unmodulated signal as a newline marker maybe?

[image: Zoomed out]

Is there a software available to decode this? Or a name for me to start reading?
Got matlab ...